# TF tree has two root node

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am building a MIT-RACECAR with ZED stereo camera and Yokuyo LiDar on it. When I visualized the /tf, it showed two trees:

One tree has 1)odom as root, then 2)base_link as second layer and then 3)Laser, Base_footprint, IMU as children of base_link

Another tree has 1)Map as root, then 2)ZED_center as second layer and then 3)ZED left camera and ZED right camera as children of ZED_Center.

I remember that tf can have only one tree, one root node. Then how can I combine the two trees into one?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297451/tf-tree-has-two-root-node/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS REP](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#relationship-between-frames) has defined the structure for linking frames together to have one single tree.

As per the REP, you would have a world frame, the child of which would be map, and the child of that would be the odom frame and so on.

---

Originally posted by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) with karma: 155 on 2018-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-16**:
Thanks, can you let me know how to make the changes? Which file I should modify?

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2018-07-16**:
I'm not entirely sure which file you'll have to modify. In ROS the most commonly used nodes for localization are gmapping (if you want to build a map) and amcl (if you want to use an existing map). Both already publish the map -> odom transform.

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2018-07-16**:
You will have to figure out what node is publishing the map frame and figure out what node is publishing the odom frame and link the two frames.

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-17**:
Hi Sidd, thanks a lot for your post. I know which node publishes odom and which one publishes map. What I need to do to link the two?

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2018-07-19**:
I would recommend going through the tutorials on the navigation stack - http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials and in particular get familiar with http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom.